# binding a property to the colomn in RadGridView in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, radgridview

I have a list of custom classes that I have bound them to the `RadGridView` through the below code:

```
this.ItemsSource = CorrelationCalibraationGridInput.ListOfCalibratableCorrelationClasses;
```

then I have created the columns manually. For one of the columns that is check box column, I need to enable disable the check box binding to a property of class and set its check state based on another property of the class.
I used the code below but the enablity does not bind to the `IsNotCalibratedYet` property. Can you explain why and how can I solve it?(note that the check state is correctly binded to the `IsCalibratedUSed` property of the class).

```
GridViewDataColumn IsCalibratedUSedColumn = new GridViewDataColumn()
{
    UniqueName = "IsCalibratedUSedColumn",
    Header = "Use calibrated",
    DataMemberBinding = new Binding("IsCalibratedUSed"),
    IsFilterable = false,
};
Binding enablityBinding = new Binding("IsNotCalibratedYet");
        enablityBinding.Mode= BindingMode.OneWay;
        enablityBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger= UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(IsCalibratedUSedColumn, GridViewDataColumn.IsEnabledProperty,enablityBinding );
        this.Columns.Add(IsCalibratedUSedColumn);
```

Comment: Where is `IsNotCalibratedYet` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `IsReadOnlyBinding` property of the `GridViewDataColumn` to your `Binding`:

```
GridViewDataColumn IsCalibratedUSedColumn = new GridViewDataColumn()
{
    UniqueName = "IsCalibratedUSedColumn",
    Header = "Use calibrated",
    DataMemberBinding = new Binding("IsCalibratedUSed"),
    IsFilterable = false,
};
Binding enablityBinding = new Binding("IsNotCalibratedYet");
enablityBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
enablityBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

IsCalibratedUSedColumn.IsReadOnlyBinding = enablityBinding;

this.Columns.Add(IsCalibratedUSedColumn);
```

Depending on whether your source property returns true/false you may want to use an `InvertedBooleanConverter`:

```
Binding enablityBinding = new Binding("IsNotCalibratedYet");
enablityBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
enablityBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
enablityBinding.Converter = new InvertedBooleanConverter();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following setting:

```
public MainWindow()
{ 
    InitializeComponent();
    lv.ItemsSource = new Item[3] { new Item() { IsNotCalibratedYet=true }, new Item() { IsNotCalibratedYet = false }, new Item() { IsNotCalibratedYet = true } };
    gv.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn()
    {
         DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("IsNotCalibratedYet"),
    });
}
```

in which:

```
public class Item
{
    public bool IsNotCalibratedYet { get; set; }
}
```

and Xaml is

```
    <ListView Name="lv" > 
        <ListView.View> 
            <GridView x:Name="gv" AllowsColumnReorder="true"
                ColumnHeaderToolTip="Employee Information">  

            </GridView> 
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```